# Is there a way to install an Android application by copying files / only modifying the file system?

Tags: android, linux, adb, root, dalvik

I was wondering if there is a way to install an Android application by just copying files and making a few changes on the filesystem?

Let's say we have `Rooted Phone 1` and `Rooted Phone 2`. We control every aspect of them (they are rooted, we control the hardware, ...). We install `App X` on `Rooted Phone 1`. What steps do we need to take to get a 1:1 copy of `App X` on `Rooted Phone 2` (without installing the app again e.g., via `adb install`)?

So far I would:

- Copy app data from `/data/data/<packagename>`
- Copy "installation data" of app from `/data/app/<packagename>-<random>`

But of course this will not be enough.

What else do we need to do? Do we need to care about `/data/dalvik-cache/`, `/data/system/packages.xml` and `/data/system/packages.list`?

Is this idea I'm having even possible?

Extra question: What things change, when Optimized Dalvik Executable (`.odex`) files are used?

Comment: prolly there is ... all you need to do is look at the source of package installer and check what it does ... but it does a lots of thing  like  creating linux user for given package(uid), it have to give right permission for this user, read manifest and modify system to know what application componet contains this package, etc ... etc ...

Comment: Yep, the permission / user issue for Sandboxing I am aware of. But creating the same user / group on `Rooted Phone 2` should suffice, as the permissions can stay the same then.
I guess you are right, I will have to look at the Package Installer in detail, I was just wondering that nobody has tried this before. Also the answer "It is not possible because ..." would be helpful so that I don't spend too many resources on analyzing the Package Installer.